# Make UITextField not to draw image attachment but keep its frame

Tags: ios, uitextfield, core-text

`UITextField` have very bad performance on drawing image attachments while scrolling on iPhone 6+/6s+. I am working on some subviews solution to overlap attachments with `UIImageView`s. It works well, but I need `UITextView` to stop drawing this attachments but keep attachment frames on their places.

I know about `NSTextContainer` `exclusionPaths` property, but not sure it will works well for async image loading. Image sizes will be known after downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found working solution by nilling `[NSTextAttachment image]` and restoring bounds:

```
CGRect bounds = attachment.bounds;
attachment.image = nil;
attachment.bounds = bounds;
```